# Android app's reading access to SD card stopped working on a specific tablet (Samsung T290) with software update

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-storage

An app developed for us (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.rff.saide.knowhow) downloads its country-specific content at its first start after selecting the country. There are two source options: from SD card or internet. The second option still works (too slow in typically bad connectivity contexts), but the first option stopped working on Samsung's T290 (many devices tested) after a software update which included an upgrade from Android 9 to 10 -- however, it is still working fine on other tablet models, like the Lenovo M8.

1st step: update to security patch May 2020: SD card option still worked
2nd step: update to patch Jul 2020 plus Android 10: SD card option DIDN'T work anymore
3rd step: update to patch Dec 2020: still no improvement

The app runs under G-Suite (managed devices, with the app being whitelisted), but Google guaranteed that this can't explain the behaviour ("if it works on one device, it will work on all").

The developer has recompiled a new version to ensure that it includes latest Android updates. He is also sure that the respective code lines can't be the reason.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

What can be the source of this problem? Does it have to be the tablet's system software?

Comment: Just post the code that does not work and post logcat with errors, exceptions and stack traces.

Comment: `There are two source options: from SD card or internet.` That is a very strange option. So you say that all those devices have a removable micro sd card inserted and the app will never use the storage provided by the device itself?

Comment: @blackapps: There are no error messages, it is just that the SD card option remains greyed out even with SD card inserted. And yes, the SD card is meant to be removed after the content upload and the routine use of the app then runs from internal storage only.

Comment: You should post the code that greys out that option. If you dont you cannot be helped.

Comment: "The developer" probably should ask by himself, because "doesn't work" is not an error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ExternalStorageSdcardAccess = function (_fileHandler, _errorHandler) {
var errorHandler = _errorHandler || _defultErrorHandler;
var fileHandler = _fileHandler || _defultFileHandler;
var root = "file:///";
return {
    scanRoot: scanRoot,
    scanPathList: scanPathList,
    scanPath: scanPath
};
function scanPath(path) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, _gotFiles, errorHandler);
}
function scanRoot() {
    scanPath(root);
}
function scanPathList(arrayOfPath) {
    arrayOfPath.forEach(function (p) {
       scanPath(p);
    });
}

function _gotFiles(entry) {
    if (entry.isFile) {
        fileHandler(entry);
    } else {
        var dirReader = entry.createReader();
        dirReader.readEntries(function (entryList) {
            entryList.forEach(function (entr) {_gotFiles(entr);});
        }, errorHandler);
    }
}

function _defultFileHandler(fileEntry) {
    console.log("FileEntry: " + fileEntry.name + " | " + fileEntry.fullPath);
}

function _defultErrorHandler(error) {
    console.log('File System Error: ' + error.code);
}
};

function getSDCardFolder() {


ExternalStorageSdcardAccess(fileHandler, fileError).scanPath("file:///storage/");

function fileHandler(fileEntry) {
    if ((fileEntry.name === app.id + "." + countryCode + '.txt') && (SDCardRoot === '')) {
       var url = fileEntry.toURL();
       SDCardRoot = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    }
function fileError(error) {}
}

function useSDCard() {
  app.request.get(SDCardRoot + app.id + "." + countryCode + ".txt", {},
   function (data) {
  if (version !== data) {
    savedVersion = data;
    if (navigator.connection.type === Connection.NONE) {
      document.getElementById('internet-update').style.opacity = 0.5;
      document.getElementById('internet-update').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
    }
    loadingContent = false;
    openUpdate();
  } else {
    app.dialog.alert('The content is up-to-date.');
    loadingContent = false;
  }
});
```

}

Comment: Hello, could you give some explanations with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Use `AndroidManifest.xml` to temporarily opt-out of scoped storage, while still targeting Android 10:

```
<!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting Android 10 or higher. -->
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" />
```

This can only be used until implementing scoped storage, because Android 11 will behave different:

> *After you update your app to target Android 11 (API level 30), the system ignores the `requestLegacyExternalStorage` attribute when your app is running on Android 11 devices, so your app must be ready to [support scoped storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) and [to migrate app data](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#migrate-legacy-storage) for users on those devices.*

See https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

[Preparing for scoped storage (Android Dev Summit '19)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnJ3amzJM94)